# How to integrate React App With Laravel Sanctum on Apache2

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, session

I use React App on localhost:3000 
For Laravel API I use apache2 from Laradock and site is:  site.localhost 
To authorize users I use Sanctum 
Problem is I can not get cookies from sanctum/csrf-cookie (i got them in response header but they are not appear in cookies) 
 and then got 419 code when i try to login via API
My .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000,site.localhost
```

And this is how i get XSRF token

```
    fetch("http://site.localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
        });
```

Is this Sanctum configuration is ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved.

1. Add the following to `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 example.com
   127.0.0.1 front.example.com
   ```
2. Then configure apache for these domains.